# Maximum distance between two non overlapping intervals

Tags: java

I am trying to find the farthest distance between two non -overlapping intervals represented as arraylist . Non-overlapping intervals are those in which the next start point does not lie between the starting point(inclusive) and ending point(exclusive) .

Example

```
Number of intervals 3

Interval 1 : 1 2

Interval 2: 3 5

Interval 3: 6 7
```

The pair of interval `(1,2)` and `(6,7)` is farthest as distance between these two is `6 -2 = 4`
So output should be `4`

My implementation

```
import java.util.*;
 class Checker implements Comparator<ArrayList>{
        public int compare(ArrayList a, ArrayList b){
          int x = (Integer)a.get(0);
          int y = (Integer)b.get(0);
          return x-y;
        }
    }
class OverlappingIntervals {
   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intervals = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            intervals.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(x, y)));
        }

        int result = overlappingIntervals(n, intervals);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static int overlappingIntervals(int n, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intervals) {
        // System.out.println(intervals);
        Checker check = new Checker();

        Collections.sort(intervals, check);
        int ans = -1;
   
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1;i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < n;j++){
                int x = (Integer)intervals.get(j).get(0)- intervals.get(i).get(1);
                if(x >= 0){     
                    if(x > ans)
                    ans = Math.max(x,ans);
                }                    
            }
        }
        return ans;            
    }        
}
```

Any better optimization for the above so to handle the constraints

```
1<=N<=10^5    
1<=l<=r<=10^6
```

l and r is the starting point and ending point of interval respectively.

Comment: If you use the `if` just do `if(x > ans) ans = x` OR just do `ans = Math.max(x,ans);` . the **if** and the **max** is redundant

Comment: **Warning**: you are using *raw types* (e.g. `ArrayList`). **Never** use raw types, always specify the necessary type arguments.

Comment: The approach is  not giving the right output for larger value of N

Comment: Further, you should write a class representing an interval, e.g. `Interval`, rather than using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Why don't you just look for the lowest interval end and the highest interval start and subtract to find the difference? That would be O(n). Unless the real assignment is more complex than you describe here. What is your question, actually? I don't really see a question in your text.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this easily using `Stack` in **O(n) + O(n*log(n))** Time & **O(n)** Space complexity.
The idea here is to merge the intervals and then check the corresponding gaps between the consecutive `Intervals`.

Here is an easy and classic approach to your problem with an illustration:

```
import java.util.*;
class OverlappingIntervals
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int n = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();

        intervals.add(new Interval(5, 14));intervals.add(new Interval(6, 9));
        intervals.add(new Interval(8, 17));intervals.add(new Interval(23, 25));
        intervals.add(new Interval(36, 56));intervals.add(new Interval(33, 45));
        intervals.add(new Interval(42, 67));intervals.add(new Interval(50, 69));
        intervals.add(new Interval(81, 95));intervals.add(new Interval(99, 111));

        int result = overlappingIntervals(intervals);
        System.out.println(result); // 82 b/w [5 , 17] & [99 , 111]
    }

    static int overlappingIntervals(ArrayList<Interval> intervals)
    {
        // Sorting all Intervals based on there `start` time
        Collections.sort(intervals, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.begin));
        int maxDistance = -1;
        
        Stack<Interval> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (Interval currInterval : intervals)
        {
            // Pushing a non-overlapping Interval
            if (stack.empty() || stack.peek().end < currInterval.begin)
                stack.push(currInterval);
            
            // Merging an overlapping Interval
            if (stack.peek().end < currInterval.end)
                    stack.peek().end = currInterval.end;
        }
        /* Now, Stack will have following merged Intervals:
           [5 , 17] <6> [23 , 25] <8> [33 , 69] <12> [81 , 95] <4> [99 , 111] */

        // Checking the gap b/w consecutive Merged-Intervals :
        Interval rightEnd = stack.pop();
        if (stack.empty()) return -1;
        Interval leftEnd = rightEnd;
        while (!stack.empty())
            leftEnd = stack.pop();
        maxDistance = rightEnd.begin - leftEnd.end;
        return maxDistance;
    }        
}
class Interval
{
    int begin, end;
    Interval(int begin, int end)
    {
        this.begin = begin; this.end = end;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    { return "[" +begin+ " , " +end+ "]"; }
}

/** [5========17]   [23=25]  [33=================================69]        [81===========95]   [99======111]
 *  5-------14      23---25      36-----------------56                      81------------95
 *   6---9                            42----------------------67                                 99------111
 *      8------17             33----------45   50----------------69                                      */
```

We can even do this without merging the intervals but I believe this approach is easier to understand.
Feel free to ask any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner("3 1 2 3 5 6 7");
int n = in.nextInt();
int minTo = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxFrom = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    maxFrom = Math.max(maxFrom, in.nextInt());
    minTo = Math.min(minTo, in.nextInt());
}
if (minTo < maxFrom)
    System.out.println("max disntance = " + (maxFrom - minTo));
else
    System.out.println("none");
```

output:

```
max disntance = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution though in C++ can be easily written in any language.

T.C - O(n + log(n))

S.C - O(1)

```
int overlappingIntervals(int n, vector<pair<int, int> >& intervals){
    sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end());
    int mi = INT_MAX;
    for(auto it: intervals){
        mi = min(it.second,mi);
    }
    return (intervals[n-1].first < mi ? -1 : intervals[n-1].first - mi);
}
```